# Apache 2.4 Always Serving Same Virtual

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I have no idea how I've misconfigured this. My Apache-fu is weak. Help, please!

I'm trying to serve two different virtual sites. I'm running on Windows.

I've set up c:/webs as my virtual root. Within c:/webs, I have 2 subfolders, c:/webs/site1 and c:/webs/site2.

The relevant entries in my configuration files, I think, are:

## httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#later
DocumentRoot "c:/webs"

<Directory "c:/webs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# at end of file
Include conf/virtuals.conf
```

## virtuals.conf:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "c:/webs/site1/public"
  ServerName site1
</virtualhost>

<virtualhost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "c:/webs/site2"
  ServerName site2
</virtualhost>
```

The problem is that no matter which URL I use, I get site1 served as the root. So the following URL's all actually point to site1:

```
http://myserver
http://myserver/site1
http://myserver/site2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did was to configure virtual hosts that would work like this (this is configured with the `ServerName` directive:

- http://site1
- http://site2

(The server name is only the part between `http://` and the next `/`, so in your case, it's only `myserver` and `site1` is just a directory on the server).

If you want the site to work like you described, 
you would configure only one virtual host and point it to `c:/webs` and then add `Alias` directives to redirect the subdirs to the `public` directories of the sites:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/webs/"
    ServerName myserver
    Alias "/site1" "c:/webs/site1/public"
    Alias "/site2" "c:/webs/site2/public"

</virtualhost>
```

BTW, the reason you always get site1 is because you don't have a matching virtualhost configuration for `http://myserver` at all, so Apache just uses the first if finds as the default, which happens to be the one for `site1`.